# get php array column value using dynamic variable

Tags: cakephp

I've  searched here and elsewhere for an answer, but can't seem to find anything that works.

I have an array `$dsxx = array("field1" => 2, "field2" => 4, "field3" => 6, "field4" => 8);`  Note my array is actually much larger, the names are more obscure and the values are all over the place.

Depending on conditions set elsewhere in my code, I need the value of a specific array element.  Let's say the code determines I need the value from `"field3"`.  I then set `$usefield = "field3"`.

I've attempted about every combination of double quotes, single quotes, curly braces, etc that I can think of, but can't get field3's value of 6 to return.  In pseudo, not working code, I need to know how to get `$answer = $dsxx[$usefield]` to return a value of 6.

Any help or pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly , Set

```
$usefield = $dsxx["field3"]
```

**$usefield** now has value **6**

If you want to change keys of your array like "field3" to "usefield" then

```
$newkey = "usefield"
$oldkey = "field3"
$dsxx[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];
unset($arr[$oldkey]);

$answer = $dsxx["usefield"]; // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

it is as simple as

```
$answer = $dsxx["field3"];
```

if you set `$usefield = "field3"` then both of the following will gave the same result.

```
$answer = $dsxx["field3"];
$answer = $dsxx[$usefield];
```

Comment: My apologies.  I simplified my example too far and unknowingly skipped the piece that's actually causing my problem.  The column name "field3" is actually stored in a MySQL table that I have available in a record set.

Comment: Thanks, now working.  I was definitely over complicating things.

Comment: happy to help :)... Please select the right answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

This code works without any problem.

Here is the 3 lines of code

```
$dsxx = array("field1" => 2, "field2" => 4, "field3" => 6, "field4" => 8);
$usefield = 'field3';
echo 'Value of field3 is: ' . $dsxx[$usefield];
```

And here is the [working demo](http://codepad.org/1mLlMq88)